# ag-grid hide checkbox in some rows depend on the cell value

Tags: angular, ag-grid

Currently I am using ag-grid to implement my table but I faced a problem.
I just want to display the checkbox in same rows only instead of all rows. May I know how to do it?

Comment: For future reference, here is complete info on [disabling checkbox in ag-grid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64012540/7977581).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-properties/#gsc.tab=0) on the column properties:

> checkboxSelection - Boolean or Function. Set to true (or return true from function) to render a selection checkbox in the column.

Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/nSoglcE17NZmvglkjGld?p=preview) with an example that puts a checkbox for people whose names start with a letter that is greater than `'M'`

The relevant code that can be found in the `app/rich-grid.component.ts`:

```
headerName: "Name",
field: "name",
checkboxSelection: params=>params.data.name[0] >'M'
```