# how to make row disabled with ag-grid?

Tags: vue.js, ag-grid

I work with **ag-grid** and i found how to make a column disabled in the doc (https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation-main/documentation.php)
but after reading doc i never find how can i make juste one row disabled.

i have already try `editable: params => params.data.active === true.`
Maybe i didn't read right or that doesn't exist. Is someone here with some soluce track ?

Comment: `editable: params => params.data.active` works. There is something else wrong with your code. Please add a [minimal reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so others will be able to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR**

There is no option in the library to make a single row disabled(both visually and keyboard event based), the only way we could make a single row disabled is by using a customCellRenderer for both header and subsequent cell checkboxes, this allows full control over the checkbox.
Besides this, there are three other ways where you can disable ag-grid checkbox based on value,

1)This is using checkBoxSelection param, it would empty the cell based on the condition.

```
checkboxSelection = function(params) {

   if (params.data.yourProperty) {
      return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

2. This would only disabled click events and style it accordingly,

```css
cellStyle: params => return params.data.status? {'pointer-events': 'none', opacity: '0.4' } : '';
```

3)This would disable it completely, as you have control over the input, but you may have to use string literals,

```
cellRenderer: (params) => {
       if (params.value) {
          return `<input type="checkbox" checked/>`;
       }
       else {
          return `<input type="checkbox" />`;
       }
 }
```

You could use `customCellRenderer(customCellRendererParams for props)`, headerCellRenderer(headerCellRendererParams for props) which accepts a complete JSX component.

4. I think this would be the most helpful, it allows you to choose the cellRenderer component based on the row value for that column. Its very well described in the [ag-grid documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering/#many-renderers-one-column).

Answer (score 1):

I think ag-grid has single row checkbox disablement available natively: https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/row-selection/#example-forcing-checkboxes-as-selected